# How to resize a form before it shows?

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that needs to contain some controls.

The controls are created dynamically and I don't know in advance the size of the form.

I'm resizing the form in the **Load** event.

Everything works propertly except the fact that when the form loads, it displays during a very short lapse of time the initial size as created by the designer than it resizes.

This behavior bothers me a little bit. I tried **PerformLayout()** but that was unsucessfull.

Does anyone know how to resize a form before it shows and when it shows, it displays directly the final size ?

```
Private sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Size = new Size(500,600)
    Me.PerformLayout()
End Sub
```

Comment: Set the size in the constructor. (After `Me.InitializeComponents`)

Comment: @Thomas Carlton, I accidentally pressed the Enter key like 3-4 times, sorry for all of the edits.

Comment: This may not be the best way, but you could set the `Opacity` of the Form to 0 and then once you have intialised what you need and the Form is ready to be shown, just set the `Opacity` to 1

Comment: There's a problem with the constructor, you certainly ought to fix it.  It is getting the native window created too early.  Actually *seeing* the window makes it very hard to explain, the content of the Call Stack window that you see when you set a breakpoint on the Load event handler would be instrumental.  Do note that hardcoding a window size is very unwise, you'll turn your window into a postage stamp on a "retina" quality display monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resize in sub new instead. After initialize component and after your controls are dynamically loaded, before form load.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    AddHandler Application.Idle, AddressOf onloaded
End Sub

Private Sub onloaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RemoveHandler Application.Idle, AddressOf onloaded

End Sub
```

and do what ever you want in form load.

valter

Comment: How is this different from a regular event handler?